# How to configure identity_cache gem to use dalli store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

Could not find the documentation to configure [identity_cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) to work with [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).  Could someone tell me how that's done?

I tried this in my `config/environments/development.rb` (I wanted to try this in development environment first):

```
config.identity_cache_store = :mem_cache_store, ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore.new(servers: ["mem"])
```

When I started rails, I saw this error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore (NameError)
```

Answer (score 4):

Set up the [Dalli gem](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).

Then create your identity cache store using:

```
Dalli::Client.new
```

... so your development.rb file will have:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
config.identity_cache_store = :dalli_store, Dalli::Client.new(:servers => ["mem1.server.com"])
```